# Unable to use the http package in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I keep getting the following error when trying to use the http package.

[image]

I already added the package in pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2 
  http: ^0.12.0+2
```

Comment: Did you remember to `pub get` to pull the packages from the repo?

Comment: Never post images of errors or output!

Comment: @Rob What do you mean?

Comment: You posted an image of the error rather than straight text of the error. Don't do that. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

in the terminal run `flutter pub get`

Comment: The package was already downloaded through saving in VS Code. I think the problem happened because initially I forgot to put the "^" with version number. I had to restart the whole project and then it started working.

Comment: Yes, when you're installing a new package, even though it automatically runs `flutter pub get` - you would still have to restart the whole app everytime you add a new package :)